# Increased max_upload_filesize, but still can't upload plugin

Tags: plugins, uploads, php.ini

I'm trying to upload a plugin (it's not available in the marketplace), that's 2.73 megabytes, but the limit is 2M. I've increased the `max_upload_filesize` variable in php.ini to 3M, but still can't upload because of the size.

I don't see a filesize set in `.htaccess`, and in the `functions.php` file it's set to 64M.

Where else can I check, that would have a max upload size that may be overriding the values mentioned above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust `post_max_size` as well (on php.ini)

Comment: This is a good suggestion. In my case the `post_max_size` was already set to 8M, but thank you for a good tip!

Answer (score 1):

After waiting a couple of days and bumping the `max_upload_filesize` to 4M from 3M, uploading the plugin worked. I am unsure if letting time pass, or increasing the value to give the upload more "room" is what solved the issue. Hopefully someone who knows more can comment...